# How to disable chromium's Certificates Pinning ?

Tags: ssl, github, certificate, chromium, pinning

Hi when I try to access some webpages, especially github.com
my chromium puts below error

`Attackers might be trying to steal your information from github.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN`

in my case, I'm under corporate's firewall and there has some security regulation.
I guess it affect the above situation.
Could anyone inform me how I can disable this warning ?

and in case of curl, it looks fine to access that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are behind a corporate firewall which does SSL interception you should install the proxy CA used for SSL interception as trusted. Once you've done this the browsers will disable certificate pinning as long as the certificate is signed by this explicitly trusted CA.

Comment: When I add the ceritificates as a Server. google, facebook works well but only github puts error. and when I add it as a Authority. all is working well. Which makes this difference ?

Comment: @keyolk: I have no idea which certificate you *"add ...  as a Server"* but you should add *the proxy CA* (i.e. the issuer of all these certificates, a single CA certificate) as a *trusted CA*. Works for me.